# Como usar o DropdownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Num arquivo **.cshtml** preciso colocar uma **DropdownListFor<>**. Ela seria populada por uma propriedade virtual, que é chave estrangeira nessa Model. Seria isso aqui no **.cshtml**:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AzureDiscountGroupId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AzureDiscountGroup????)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Preciso mostrar a descrição e o valor do desconto, mas no change, filtrar pelo ID do desconto. Como faria isso?

Comment: acho que a forma legal de fazer isso é criar uma propriedade no backend que já retorne formatado.

Comment: @rLinhares, não entendi. Como faria isso?

Comment: Se eu criar uma outra Model para isso, posso usar essa Model na View junto com a outra view?

Comment: `AzureDiscountGroup` é um `IEnumerable`?

Comment: é um `public virtual AzureDiscountGroup  AzureDiscountGroup  { get; set; }`

Comment: [Esse exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/358689/35358) te ajuda? O select list vc pode montar lendo as informações da sua propriedade.

Comment: @pnet isso > `public virtual AzureDiscountGroup AzureDiscountGroup { get; set; }` não é uma lista, como pretende transformar em um DropdownListFor<>? Pode tentar melhorar a pergunta?

Answer (score 3):

Olá, boa noite!

Não sei se entendi bem o que você precisa, mas acho que esse modelo abaixo poderá ajudá-lo a ter uma ideia de como resolver sua questão:

Obs.: Esse é um exemplo bem didático e, principalmente no controller eu adicionei opções à mão e não buscando de um banco de dados para ficar mais fácil de explicar. Contudo, essa solução pode ser melhorada.

Model:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListaDeDescontoTratada { get; set; }
public string DescontoEscolhido { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DescontoEscolhido, Model.ListaDeDescontoTratada, new { @id = "ListaDeDescontos", size = 1, @class = "form-control", MultiSelectList = "false" })
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult LocalOndeTemDesconto()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> descontosListados = new List<SelectListItem>();
            string descontoEscolhido = string.Empty;


                SelectListItem Item1 = new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = "Desconto 1: 10%",
                    Value = "D1"
                };

                SelectListItem Item2 = new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = "Desconto 2: 20%",
                    Value = "D2"
                };

                SelectListItem Item3 = new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = "Desconto 3:  30%",
                    Value = "D3"
                };

                descontosListados.Add(Item1);
                descontosListados.Add(Item2);
                descontosListados.Add(Item3);

            LocalOndeTemDescontoModel localOndeTemDescontoModel = new LocalOndeTemDescontoModel()
            {
                DescontoEscolhido = descontoEscolhido,
                DescontosListados = descontosListados
            };

            return View(localOndeTemDescontoModel);
        }
```